# Skin of chicken like chicken meat itself?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, parts-of-the-body, derabanan

In terms of dinei baser b'chalav and other nafka minas for if something is considered baser or not what does the status of the skin on top of chicken have (the skin that is cooked together and often eaten with the chicken meat itself.) Although the issur baser b'chalav by chicken is anyway m'drabbanan so the nafka minas might not be so many however perhaps the skin although it might still ossur from the point of the issur of baser b'chalav still it might not have the din of "baser" making it more disconnected from the issur (might be considered now "two d'rabbanans if we'd be dealing with a shailo of baser b'chalav.)

The SA in [YD Siman 87 SIf 7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96) already deals with cases where one wouldn't be chayiv on the issur of baser b'chalav. Over there "oir" is counted among the things. However since the Shulchan Aruch is seemingly discussing animal meat since it uses a lashon of "patur" therefore I want to know if chicken skin is any different. Again the nafka minah would be difficult to find since chicken is itself a d'rabbanan. If the skin of the chicken itself is not considered to be like the baser but would still create an issur of baser b'chalav to some degree then perhaps it would be 2 d'rabbanans. Maybe that would be the application in terms of chicken skin based on Siman 87 Sif 7. However I'm in doubt as to whether it's speaking about an edible skin which might be different. Although as pointed out in the sif there it lists other parts of the animal which are in fact edible.

Comment: Why do you think the Shulchan Aruch there has anything to do with if it's edible? It also list the placenta which is edible in all (most?) animals.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Badei Hashulchan (87:101) brings the Pri Megadim and Aruch Hashulchan who suggest that soft skin such as the skin of a שליל (fetus), the tail of an animal where there is no hair and the womb of the female should be considered Basar B'Chalav mi'doraysa. This is based on Rambam (Hil Ma'achlos Assuros 4:21) that such edible skins are considered meat in regards to the prohibition of neviala, treifa, and tomei. [However see footnote 209 there that there may be a difference between those laws and basar b'chalav]. However, they do not discuss chicken skin, presumably because regardless it would d'rabanan.

Answer (score 0):

The Mishna in Chulin (9,2) states that soft, edible skin is considered meat. The Talmud references this Mishna in several places. As a result, one must consume these parts of the Paschal sacrifice, and they accept Tumah, and they can cause Pigul, among other things. Presumably it is considered meat with respect to Basar bChalav.