# Is fur fleishig?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat

Is fur fleishig?

My thinking is, not edible -> not food -> not fleishig. But I dunno. (This question is pure silliness and not practical.)

Comment: Or in Hebrew: האם פרווה בשרי? Anyways, it would seem it's Parve, reading between the lines here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21943/501

Comment: How about fur from a non kosher animal?

Comment: Weren't there more comments here last night? Did they get deleted?

Comment: Is shown in the answer, the question is actually a serious question; not because of eating, but because of the possibility of cooking fur in milk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in Shulchan Aruch. See [Yoreh De'ah 87:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.87.7?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) that says that one is Patur (exempt from punishment) if one cooks hides in milk.

> המבשל שליל בחלב חייב וכן האוכלו אבל המבשל שליא או **עור** וגידים ועצמות ועיקרי קרנים וטלפים הרכים פטור וכן האוכלם פטור:‏

> One who cooks an embryo in milk is liable, and one who eats them cooked together is liable. But cooking the placenta, **skin**, tendons, bones, ikari karnaim (The part of the horn that is found below the skin) ,or soft hooves [in milk] is exempt [from the Torah] and one who eats them is exempt.

However, it's not permissible to do so, as the [Kaf Hachaim mentions](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.87.7?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.87.66.1&lang2=bi), with sources.

> סו) [סעיף ז'] המבשל שליל וכו' אבל המבשל שליא או עור וכו' פטור. וכן האוכלם פטור. **אבל איסורא מיהא איכא בין באכילה בין בבישול**. ש"ך ס"ק כ"ב. פר"ח או' ך' לה"פ או' י"ד. בל"י או' י"ד. הל"פ בסעי' זה. שפ"ד או' כ"ב. חכ"א כלל מ' סוף או' ו' בי"צ או' ט' ערוך השלחן או' כ"ט. זב"צ או מ"ט.‏

Seems that it is considered to be a Rabbinical decree - it's fleishig deRabanan.

Comment: Hair is not on that list, and is plausibly not subject to the rabbinic prohibition as less similar to real meat

Comment: @DoubleAA - I assumed the OP meant a fur coat, not strands of fur/hair.

Comment: @DannySchoemann That's an interesting assumption

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger - can you be the referee - what are you asking about? Animal hair or animal hides?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I meant hair